# .NET DLL in Delphi service Memory LEak

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, dll, memory-leaks

This is a special problem with detecting a memory leak.

I have a service, written in delphi, that starts many .NET Dll's. One of those DLL's hast a memory leak. 
I actually know which one it is, but I can't find it in the code.

The problem is, i can't use any .NET memory leak finder, because the service is written in delphi.
Is there a easy way to find the leak?

Edit:
This is a part of the mentioned DLL. I suspect the following part to cause the leak:

```
for( i = 0; i <10; i++)
{
    DivaCall call = DivaVariables.InstObj.CreateCall();
   //Some channel options
   Thread t = new Thread(() => machineManager(call);
   t.Start() //In this thread I call somebody, do something and disconnect again
}
```

Maybe It would be good to mention, that the sense of this DLL is, to call people and inform them on something.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you able to use reflector/ilspy?

Comment: Write a .net program to flush it out. Then use .net leak detection tools.

Comment: Thats nearly impossible.
The call of the dll is just too complex. :/ Isn't there another way?

Comment: If service loads .NET CLR into the process (how else it can run code from .NET dlls?) [JetBrains dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/) can profile it.

Comment: Nearly impossible? How did you manage to call this DLL in the first place?

Comment: I can't use dotMemory. "Unable to attach the profiler because app uses garbage collection".
But I can't disable it, because my process is loading many DLL's and I can't disable it everywhere.

@DavidHeffernan I did not make this service in the first place.

Comment: So disable concurrent garbage collection. If you aren't able to work with the source code to the DLL, what chance do you have of changing anything? If understanding the DLL is beyond you then surely you need to go back to the original developer. Finally, perhaps the leak is actually down to code outside this DLL. The leaked memory is allocated in the DLL, but leaked because the calling code is wrong?

Comment: I think you got me wrong:
I am the developer of the DLL.

Comment: @xileb0 Concurent GC is disabled for a process, not for each DLL and does not require to change a code. Create a file named "YourExe.exe.config" and place near YourExe.exe. Add this text to the file 
`<configuration>
   <runtime>
       <gcConcurrent enabled="false"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>`

and use dotMemory to find and issue

Comment: If you develop the DLL, are you really unable to call it from managed code? And yes, if you want to profile, you will be able to, you just have to try harder.